# How can I determine which process is moving a file?

Tags: windows

We have a website that produces files, which are dropped into a folder and scooped by another process that copies the files to another server (not my design).

In our production environment, the move is performed by a scheduled task that fires every minute, which calls a batch file, that calls a powershell script that actually moves the files (again, not my design).

Now the question:

The website is set up identically in our UAT environment. The files are dropped in a folder, and then moved. But there is no scheduled task on that box, and I am having a hell of a time determining what process is actually moving the files.

It might not even be executing on the same machine as the folder.  Any idea how I can determine what process is moving the files, or at least what machine is doing it?

Answer (score 2):

You can use SysInternals process monitor and filter for filesystem entries with the path or filename of the moved files.  If it is a local process, this should reveal it.  If it is not a local process, then you will see the files being moved by "System" or something like that.

Unfortunately, you have to be running process monitor at the moment that the moving is taking place, and process monitor is somewhat heavy, so the entire server may suffer while you are troubleshooting.

If the files are being moved by a remote process, you can use SysInternals PsFile or some similar utility to find out who is accessing them.

SysInternals Home: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/default

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with security audit logging on the file and on the directories ("folders") in question.

First, run Group Policy (`gpedit.msc`) as Administrator. In the left pane navigate to Computer Configuration | Windows Settings | Security Settings | Local Policies | Audit Policy. In the right pane, set both "Audit object access" and "Audit process tracking" to enable on Success. (Not much point in auditing on failure, since failed attempted accesses won't result in moving a file!)

OR - if you are running Windows 7 or later, you can choose to do it this way: In the left pane, navigate to Computer Configuration | Windows Settings | Security Settings | Advanced Audit Policy | System Audit Policies . Under "Detailed Tracking", enable "Audit Process Creation" for Success. Under "Object Access", enable "Audit File System" for Success. This method will generate somewhat fewer spurious entries in your event log. NOTE: If anything is set to anything other than "Not configured" under "Advanced Audit Policy", it is better to make subsequent changes here as well, as making settings both here and in the less-fine-detailed "Audit policy" described in the previous paragraph may produce strange results.

Next: In Explorer, go to the source directory of the move. Right-click on  a directory, select Properties, then the Security tab, then click "Advanced" (almost anything worthwhile is always under an "Advanced" tab or button...). Click the "Auditing" tab, then "Continue", then "Add". The resulting dialog will look just like the one for adding an entry to a "permissions list", but in this case, the entry(ies) you create will determine that the indicated operations are to be audited - i.e. audit log entries will be created for them.

For a "Principal", use the "Everyone" group. For "Type" you probably only want "success" (again, failed attempts obviously won't move any files). "Applies to:" select "This folder, subfiles and files". Select all of the "advanced permissions".

Repeat for the destination directory.

If the file in question already exists in the source directory you could enable auditing just for that file rather than the directory it's in (but enable it for the destination directory as well).

All successful attempts to access to the directory(ies), or the file if you enabled auditing at that level, will now be reflected in the Security log.

To view the audit entries go to Computer Management, System Tools |Event Viewer, Windows Logs, and select the Security log. Correlate the log entries for the file/directory access with the process creation entries.

Audit entries often take a minute or two to show up in Event Viewer. Don't be afraid to use Refresh a few times.

n.b.: Security audit log entries for "object access" (including files) indicate only the times the objects were *opened* for access, not the times they were actually operated on and not the specific operations.

For example: if someone opens a file for read and write access, that generates an audit entry. Subsequent actual reads and writes to the file do *not* generate audit entries. And it will be impossible to tell from the audit log whether the file was actually written to - only that it was opened in such a way as to permit writing. To get those details you will have to use Process Monitor as described by Mike Nakis.